# How to calculate vector that is perpendicular to the direction of moving in Flash?

Tags: flash, vector

In flash i have a class that extends movieclip and i am moving it forward, up and down, and rotating it. How can i calculate the vector that is perpendicular to this movieclip?

Answer (score 4):

Well as explained [here](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-2/) it is pretty easy to get the perpendicular vector from the movement vector:

> Let's say you have a boat that has cannons that fire to the left and
>   right. Given that the boat is facing along the direction vector (2,1),
>   in which directions do the cannons fire? This is easy in 2D: to rotate
>   90 degrees clockwise, just flip the two vector components, and then
>   switch the sign of the second component. (a,b) becomes (b,-a). So, if
>   the boat is facing along (2,1), the right-facing cannons fire towards
>   (1,-2). The left-facing cannons fire in the opposite direction, so we
>   flip both signs to get: (-1,2).

So you just need to calculate the direction vector and then do what they said. Now how exactly you should calculate the direction vector will depend on your specific implementation; since you haven't provided us any code I'm not sure what you are doing.

However I'll give an explanation based on one common implementation; you simply store the scalar speed of the moving object, and every frame calculate a movement vector based on that speed and the rotation. In that case the movement vector is calculated using simple trigonometry, something like:

```
x = cos(rot) * speed
y = sin(rot) * speed
movement = [x, y]
```

Answer (score 0):

In 3D, I'd just take the cross product of the movement vector and the up vector.

Comment: The OP is extending Flashs *MovieClip*, so this is definitely 2D space.

Comment: @bummzack: True, I was just pointing things out how I'd do it in 3D.