# Moving along a flat plane with accordance to camera view

Tags: xna, 3d, mathematics

I'm making a 3D game, and I'm stuck on a little experiment.

I currently have a flat plane with a free camera running around, and a sphere (really, a light approximated as a sphere) that rests above the surface of the plane at, say, 50 units up. I'm trying to move the sphere, and I can do this easily by simply adding to the position in the X and Z direction. However, I got a bit messed up because when I move the camera, pressing the left arrow might move the sphere to the right, because of the coordinates. So I'm trying to move the sphere along the X and Z dependant on where my camera is looking.

For example, if I was looking at it from behind, down on an angle, I expect the sphere to move to the camera's left along the plane, or move down towards the camera, still along the plane.

I have seemed to get left and right working with
`a.Position -= Vector3.Cross(((FreeCamera)camera).Forward, ((FreeCamera)camera).Up);` but trying to move the sphere using just the camera's forward causes the sphere to move into or out of the plane, depending on the angle of the camera (this makes sense, because the camera's forward may be pointing into the plane).

My question is, how do I move an object left or right along a plane (remaining 50 units above the Y axis) in accordance to the camera's direction? For example, viewing the plane from its left facing towards the center, moving left should make it move towards the top of the plane if viewed from the back or to the camera's local left.

Here's two screenshots showing what I mean:

When viewing the red light from here:
[image: Starting position]
Pressing right should give me this. Notice how the red sphere has moved (disregard the fact the camera angle changed slightly):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Camera class generates a View matrix right? Multiplying a position in world space by the view matrix results in that same position being transformed into view space. Conversely, if you multiply a position in view space by the inverse of your view matrix, you'll get your position back in world space. On to your question.

**Part 1) Moving light in relation to the camera**

So you'd like to move the light position according to the camera's current orientation. An easy way to do this is simply to apply the transformation in view space (as opposed to world space). As an example:

```cs
Vector3 viewLightPosition = Vector3.Transform(light.Position, camera.ViewMatrix);
if(keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) viewLightPosition += Vector3.Right * moveSpeed * dt;
light.Position = Vector3.Transform(viewLightPosition, Matrix.Invert(camera.ViewMatrix));
```

That takes care of the problem where movement should always be relative to the camera.

**Part 2) Clamping the light back onto the correct plane**

In step 1 the light was moved according to the camera, but disregarding the plane. Now it's time to fix that, i.e. you need to validate the light position to ensure that it remains at the same distance from the plane. The first thing that occurs to me would be:

1. Project your light position *into* the plane.
2. Then move it out of the plane by the desired amount along the plane's normal.

I'm not sure but I think XNA's [Matrix.CreateShadow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createshadow.aspx) could be leveraged to simplify the first step. Once again, example:

```cs
Matrix projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreateShadow(plane.Normal, plane);
light.Position = Vector3.Transform(light.Position, projectionMatrix);
light.Position += plane.Normal * distance;
```

**Note) Calculating the correct plane for your wall**

Of course part 2 only works if you're using the correct plane. Since the Plane is usually stored as a Normal and Distance from the origin, it might be hard to come up with the correct values to fit a specific object in the world.

Luckily the Plane class also has a constructor that makes this task easy - you only need to pass it three points that lie on the plane. So to create a plane for your wall, all you'd have to do is:

```cs
Plane plane = new Plane(wall.Vertices[0], wall.Vertices[1], wall.Vertices[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On Part 2 of your answer, it does not seem to work as given (the first CreateShadow() causes it to disappear, which I assume means it fell through; the negated version gives a weird flickering) but I still have to check to make sure my plane is defined correctly (as my plane is right now a mesh). Also, the idea about moving the light out along the normal sounds like a good idea, so I'll take a look at it again a bit later. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know how it turns out, I've never used CreateShadow in this kind of situation, but logic tells me it should work, since it's just a matrix that projects points into a plane along some specified direction. And by the way, don't do this every frame. Only do it when there's user input and the position was changed. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get this to work. One issue was that it would always flicker (I tracked the position and seemed that X would invert) and after transforming it back to the plane, it wouldn't move at all.

Comment: Could you post the relevant portion of the code to pastebin or something? And is that flickering related to part 1 or part 2? I've used the procedure described in part 1 before with no problems so there shouldn't be any problem there. As for part 2, I'm really not seeing why it might fail either..

Comment: I'm running some tests now, will get back to you soon. Part 1 is working well. Part 2 is indeed giving the behavior you describe. Looking into it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm away from the computer right now, but the flickering happened to me on part 2.

Comment: Okay I've finished running my tests, and everything seems to be working correctly now. The plane.Normal should **not** be inverted after all - that was the one and only reason for the flickering. Once I fixed that, everything else seems to be working fine. I'll update my post with my test scenario, compare it with yours. Check your plane too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the time you spent on this question! I confirmed your code works, though I had to use Vector3.Up as the Up vector for my plane, not with Vector3.Backward. Inexplicably, when I changed the old code I was trying to the normal of the plane, not the inverse, it worked - odd because I swear I tried that. I must have mixed something up during that test. Anyhow, thank you again for your time!

Comment: @DMan No problem! But just in case you're not calculating the plane correctly for your wall, and also for clarification: you mention the plane having an up vector, but what the plane has is a **normal**, which doesn't necessarily point up. In my example I made a diagonal plane (up + backward) but of course you have to create a plane that corresponds to the wall *in your scene*. A plane can be constructed from three points. So you could take three of the corners of your wall and create the plane from them (although you'd have to look online for the formula, it's not too hard though).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. In case you are wondering, I figured out while my initial test did not work - I set my plane's `d` to 500, assuming it was the width of the plane (which doesn't make any sense considering it is a plane) then switched to the negated normal, when I finally realized my plane was set wrong, but did not try it with the normal again. Oops!

Comment: Yeah I figured the plane must have been wrong. The `D` in the plane stands for distance, i.e. its distance from the (in this case) world's origin. In other words, if you were standing at the origin and started travelling in the direction of the plane's normal, how many units it would take until you intersected the plane - that's D. Since that's harder to visualize, [you should use the alternate constructor that takes 3 points instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195916.aspx). I failed to notice it already existed in the framework yesterday. :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include that extra bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the camera's rotation around the Y axis and use that with trig functions to calculate the X and Z distances:

x = cos(angle) * speed

z = sin(angle) * speed

btw an answer I gave to a different question described the same math for a slightly different situation https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/18395/6588

Comment: Excuse my midway-through-highschool math understanding, but I have my camera's rotation around the Y (the Yaw, in radians). `Atan2` accepts `(y,x)`. So am I trying to solve for `x`? If so, would `Yaw=Atan2(y,x)` and what does `y` stand for then?

Comment: oops I got my trig functions confused, that should be sine and cosine not arc-tangent. edited

Comment: I think I'm missing something here; say if I passed `something.Position += new Vector3((float)(Math.Cos(((FreeCamera)camera).Yaw)), 0, (float)(Math.Sin(((FreeCamera)camera).Yaw))) * timeConstant;`, this won't take in account to the direction I pressed, even if I add/subtract it. Left/right movement seems to be working if I negate the Cos and Sin respectively, but I can't figure it out for up/down.

Comment: I still cannot get this implementation to work; at best, it moves left and right in the correct direction, but it will never move up/down no matter how I switch the signs.